# Как выровнять содержимое таблицы?

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ввв</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table width=1000 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1>
<tr>
<td colspan=3><a href="uu.html"><img src="head.jpg"></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="about.html"><img src="about.jpg"></a></th>
<td rowspan=5>gfdgfdgfgfdgfdgfdgfdgfdgfgdgfdgfdfd</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="poleznoe.html"><img src="poleznoe.jpg"></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="friends.html"><img src="friends.jpg"></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="uspehi.html"><img src="uspehi.jpg"></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="contacts.html"><img src="contacts.jpg"></a></th>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему-то отображается не так! Я добавил туда кнопки и сделал шапку - получилось так, что меню уехало вправо! Что делать?

Comment: прочитайте как делать таблицы на html, а потом замените все <th> на <td>, а потом будет тема для разговора.

Comment: заменил, что дальше?

Comment: меняйте `</th>` на `</td>`. Что за детский сад?
зачем `colspan`?

Comment: Ну, а почему уезжает-то?

Comment: зачем colspan?
что получиться-то должно?

Comment: В общем, примитивный сайт,  меню крепится с боку к шапке. Но почему-то меню выехало на середину шапки. Не могу понять почему...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам необходимо выровнять по центру содержимое таблицы.
Воспользуйтесь стилем “*css*”.

Добавьте между тегами <head> и </head>:

```
<style type="text/css">

td {text-align:center;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Материал для раздумий:

- [Теги](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tegi);
- [Тег `<td>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/td).

Answer (score 1):

Если тег открывается `<td>`, то закрывайте тоже его же `</td>`, а не `</th>`.